# Не выполняется программа MPI. Пустая консоль

Tags: mpi

Доброе время суток!

Подскажите, где косяки в программе. Решаю такую задачу на Си++ с применением MPI (обратите внимание на то, что нельзя использовать коллективные обмены):

> Племя кроманьонцев охотится на пещерного медведя, который спит в своем логове в одной из пещер. Для этого они разделяются и начинают заглядывать во все пещеры подряд до тех пор, пока один из них не найдет медведя. Так как крики могут разбудить медведя раньше времени, нашедший медведя находит каждого из своих товарищей и шепотом сообщает ему, что медведь найден. Написать программу, моделирующую поведение племени, исключающую коллективные обмены.

Проблема в том, что в консоли ничего не происходит. Точнее массив создается, заполняется элементами и выводится на экран, а вот сами функции MPI не отрабатывают - курсор просто мигает.

Заранее скажу, что пробовал использовать MPI_Isend и MPI_Wait, но без толку
Вот мой говнокод )) :

```
    введите сюда код
#include<mpi.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<stdio.h>
#define TegN 1
#define TegAreaBear 2
#define TegAreaBearTail 3
#define TegBearPositionNul 4
#define TegBearPosition 5

using namespace std;

// Определяем медведя в одну из пещер
// элементы = -1 - это пустые пещеры
// элементы = 1 - это искомая пещера
void BearSleep (int* AreaBear, int N) {

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        AreaBear[i] = -1;
    }

    int k = rand() %N;
    AreaBear[k] = 1;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        cout << AreaBear[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}

// Ищем пещеру с медведем. Если элемент равен 1, то возвращаем номер пещеры
int search(int* arr, int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 1) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}



int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    // N - число пещер, size - количество процессов (кроманьонцев), rank - номер процесса
    int size, rank;

    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);


    if (rank == 0) {
        int N;
        cout << "Ukazite kolichestvo peshcher" << endl;
        cin >> N;
        cout << "Kolichestvo peshcher = " << N << endl;

        // Инициализируем территорию поиска - массив пещер
        int* AreaBear = new int[N]; 
        // Определяем медведя в одну из пещер
        BearSleep(AreaBear, N);

        // Нулевому процессу отдаем его часть массива - голову массива
        int* AreaBearHead = new int[N/size];
        for (int i=0; i<N/size; i++) {
            AreaBearHead[i] = AreaBear[i];
        }

        //Остальным процессам будем передавать хвост массива
        int* AreaBearTail = new int[N - N/size];
        for (int i=0; i<N - N/size; i++) {
            AreaBearTail[i] = AreaBear[i+N/size];
        }

        // Передаем процессам размер N
        for (int r=1; r<size; r++) {
            MPI_Send(&N, 1, MPI_INT, r, TegN, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        // Передаем процессам массив-хвост
        for (int r=1; r<size; r++) {
            MPI_Send(&AreaBearTail[r*N/size], N/size, MPI_INT, r, TegAreaBearTail, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        // На нулевом процессе ищем пещеру в массиве-голове
        int BearPositionNul = search(AreaBearHead, N/size);
        // Если нашли, то передаем процессам индекс пещеры 
        // и пишем сообщение, что нулевой процесс теперь знает, где медведь
        if (BearPositionNul >= 0) {
            for (int r=1; r<size; r++) {
                MPI_Send(&BearPositionNul, 1, MPI_INT, r, TegBearPositionNul, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
            printf ("\n Now hunter %3d know where bear is slepping. This cave %3d", rank, BearPositionNul);
        }

        // Если индекс пещеры обнаружен на другом процессе, то принимаем информацию от него
        int BearPosition;
        for (int i=1; i<size; i++) {
            MPI_Recv(&BearPosition, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, TegBearPosition, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf ("\n Now hunter %3d know where bear is slepping. This cave %3d", rank, BearPosition);
        }
    }

    else {
        int N;
        // Принимаем размер массива N от нулевого процесса
        MPI_Recv(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, TegN, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        // Инициализируем массив-приемник
        // И принимаем массив-хвост из нулевого процесса
        int* AreaBearTail = new int[N/size];; 
        MPI_Recv(AreaBearTail, N/size, MPI_INT, 0, TegAreaBearTail, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        // Покажем эти части
        for (int i=0; i<N/size; i++) {
            cout << AreaBearTail[i] << " ";
        }

        // Каждый процесс ищет пещеру на своем участке
        int BearPosition = search(AreaBearTail, N/size);

        // Если пещера найдена, то отправляем индекс всем процессам, кроме себя
        // Процессы осуществляют прием сообщения
        if (BearPosition >= 0) {

            // от нулевого процесса до текущего
            for (int j=0; j<rank; j++) {
                MPI_Send(&BearPosition, 1, MPI_INT, j, TegBearPosition, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Recv(&BearPosition, 1, MPI_INT, rank, TegBearPosition, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            }

            // с послетекущего до последнего
            for (int j=rank+1; j<size; j++) {
                MPI_Send(&BearPosition, 1, MPI_INT, j, TegBearPosition, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Recv(&BearPosition, 1, MPI_INT, rank, TegBearPosition, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            }

            // Все процессы с первого сообщают, что они знают, где медведь
            for (rank=1; rank<size; rank++) {
                printf ("\n Now hunter %3d know where bear is slepping. This cave %3d", rank, BearPosition);
            }
        }

        // Принимаем сообщение от нулевого процесса, что он нашел пещеру с медведем
        int BearPositionNul;
        MPI_Recv(&BearPositionNul, 1, MPI_INT, 0, TegBearPositionNul, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        printf ("\n Now hunter %3d know where bear is slepping. This cave %3d", rank, BearPositionNul);
    }


    MPI_Finalize();
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

ДОБАВИЛ СОКРАЩЕННЫЙ КОД ДЛЯ ОТЛАДКИ
Решил пройти по шагам, постепенно навешивая на него все остальное. В нем нулевой процесс передает размер массива, сам массив по частям и результат поиска, остальные все это принимают. Если нулевой процесс нашел, то выводит сообщение. Такое же сообщение должны выводить остальные процессы, но они не выводят.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#define TegN 1
#define TegAreaBear 2
#define TegAreaBearTail 3
#define TegBearPositionNul 4
#define TegBearPosition 5

using namespace std;

// Все пустые пещеры = минус единица, искомая пещера = +1
void BearSleep (int* AreaBear, int N) {
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        AreaBear[i] = -1;
    }

//  srand(time(NULL));
    int k = rand() %N; // Рандомно выбираем номер пещеры
    AreaBear[k] = 1; // И помечаем эту пещеру единицей

    // Выводим массив пещер на экран
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        cout << AreaBear[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// Функция поиска пещеры
int search(int* SearchMishu, int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (SearchMishu[i] == 1) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

void main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int N, N1, size, rank; // Количество пещер, количество кроманьонцев, номер кроманьонца
    int BearPosition, BearPosition1;
    int* AreaBearRank;
    int* AreaBearRank1;

    MPI_Status status, st, draf;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);


    if (rank == 0) {

        cout << "Ukazite kolichestvo peshcher" << endl;
        cin >> N;
        cout << "Kolichestvo peshcher = " << N << endl;

        int* AreaBear = new int[N]; //Массив - количество пещер
        BearSleep(AreaBear, N);

        AreaBearRank = new int[N/size + N%size];

        for (int i=0; i<(N/size+N%size); i++) {
            AreaBearRank[i] = AreaBear[i];
        }

        for (int i=0; i<N/size+N%size; i++) {
            cout << "Rank number" << rank << "   Elem:" << AreaBearRank[i] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }

        for (int i=1; i<size; i++) {
            MPI_Send(&N, 1, MPI_INT, i, TegN, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        for (int i=1; i<size; i++) {
            MPI_Send(&AreaBear[i*N/size+N%size], N/size, MPI_INT, i, TegAreaBear, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        BearPosition = search(AreaBearRank, N/size + N%size);
        if (BearPosition >= 0) {
            cout << "I am " << rank << " know the number. This is " << BearPosition << endl;
            for (int i=1; i<size; i++) {
                MPI_Send(&BearPosition, 1, MPI_INT, i, TegBearPosition, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
        }

    }

    if (rank>0) {
        MPI_Recv(&N1, 1, MPI_INT, 0, TegN, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        AreaBearRank1 = new int[N1/size];

        MPI_Recv(AreaBearRank1, N1/size, MPI_INT, 0, TegAreaBear, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &st);

        for (int i=0; i<N1/size; i++) {
            cout << "Rank number" << rank << "   Elem:" << AreaBearRank1[i] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }

        MPI_Recv(&BearPosition1, 1, MPI_INT, rank, TegBearPosition, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &draf);
        if (BearPosition1 >= 0) {
            cout << "I am " << rank << " know the number. This is " << BearPosition1 << endl;
        }

    }   



MPI_Finalize();
system("pause");    
}
```

ВЫВОД ДО ОШИБКИ

```
Ukazite kolichestvo peshcher
13
Kolichestvo peshcher = 13
-1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
Rank number0   Elem:-1
Rank number0   Elem:-1
Rank number0   Elem:1
Rank number0   Elem:-1
I am 0 know the number. This is 2
Rank number3   Elem:-1
Rank number2   Elem:-1
Rank number1   Elem:-1
Rank number3   Elem:-1
Rank number2   Elem:-1
Rank number1   Elem:-1
Rank number3   Elem:-1
Rank number2   Elem:-1
Rank number1   Elem:-1
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас неправильный порядок вызовов `MPI_Send` и `MPI_Recv` в корневом и некорневых процессах. Он должен быть обратным. Если в корневом это send-receive, то в некорневых должно быть receive-send. Или наоборот.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду последние три строки в блоке else? Или принцип построения: MPI_Send 1, MPI_Send 2, MPI_Send 3 в нулевом, MPI_Recv 1, MPI_Recv 2, MPI_Recv 3 в некорневых (цифра это типо блок информации) ?

Comment: Я имею в виду парные вызовы `MPI_Send(&BearPosition ...` и `MPI_Recv(&BearPosition ...`

Comment: понял. Сейчас подумаю, как исправить. Пока закомментил эти строки, оставил в нулевом передачу размера массива и самого массива, в корневых прием размера массива и самого массива и вывод элементов массива на экран. Консоль также ничего не выводит. При закрытии консоли успевает выдать сообщение: unable to read the cmd header on the left child context. Other MPI error, error stack: ReadFailed (1317) и далее абракадабра

Comment: Ни у кого не мыслей по поводу данной ошибки?

Comment: @Артур добавьте в вопрос все, что выводится в консоль

Comment: Прикрепил бы скрин, да не могу понять как. Выводит следующее: unable to read the cmd header on the left child context. Other MPI error, error stack: ReadFailed (1317) [абракадабра]  (errno 10054).  Aborting: mpiexec on [абракадабра] failed to communicate with smpd on [абракадабра]. Other MPI error, error stack:  ReadFailed (1317):  [абракадабра]  (errno 10054)

Comment: меня интересует консольный вывод **до** ошибки.

Comment: Igor, в первый пост добавил код, который сейчас использую для отладки.  после него результат вывода до ошибки